# tkinter cant assign text variable

Tags: python, tkinter

the problem was my input popup had to be a toplevel window so changing tk.Tk() to tk.Toplevel() makes it work fine ;)

```
#Josh Harrison
#3008088

from graphics import *
from random import randrange

import winsound, sys

#scale for size of squares
scale = 50

#setupBoard sets up the board with a randomly generated puzzle
def setupBoard(size, color):
    board = [[[0, Rectangle(Point(scale*.05,scale*.05),Point(scale*.95,scale*.95))] for x in range(size)] for x in range(size)]
    for x in range(size):
        for y in range(size):
            board[x][y][1] = Rectangle(Point(x*scale+scale*.05,y*scale+scale*.05),Point(x*scale+scale*.95,y*scale+scale*.95))
    for i in range(1):
        selectTile(board, Point(randrange(size)*scale,randrange(size)*scale), size, color)
    return board

#selectTile does the action for selecting tiles
#set color to 0 for black and white and 1 for color rotation
def selectTile(board,point,size,color):
    #sets value switch according to if colors are desired or not
    if color == 1:
        valueSwitch = colorSwitch
    else:
        valueSwitch = bwSwitch
    x = int(point.getX()/scale)
    y = int(point.getY()/scale)
    #temp is made to preserve the selected tiles state
    temp = board[x][y][0]
    #swap all square values
    #note try and except are also looped
    for i in range(3):
        for z in range(3):
            try:
                board[x-1+i][y-1+z][0] = valueSwitch(board[x-1+i][y-1+z][0])
            except:
                #overlap fix for x maxed
                if x == size - 1 and y != size - 1:
                    board[0][y-1+z][0] = valueSwitch(board[0][y-1+z][0])
                #overlap fix for y maxed
                if y == size - 1 and x != size - 1:
                    board[x-1+i][0][0] = valueSwitch(board[x-1+i][0][0])
    #overlap fix for bottom right corner
    if x == size - 1 and y == size - 1:
        board[0][0][0] = valueSwitch(board[0][0][0])
        for a in range(2):
            board[0][size-a-1][0] = valueSwitch(board[0][size-a-1][0])
            board[size-a-1][0][0] = valueSwitch(board[size-a-1][0][0])    
    #give middle square initial value again
    board[x][y][0] = temp

#updateBoard updates the squares to the right colour according to value        
def updateBoard(board, size, count):
    if count != 0:
        winsound.Beep(333, 200)
    for x in range(size):
        for y in range(size):
            if board[x][y][0] == 0:
                board[x][y][1].setFill('white')
            elif board[x][y][0] == 1:
                board[x][y][1].setFill('yellow')  
            elif board[x][y][0] == 2:
                board[x][y][1].setFill('green')
            elif board[x][y][0] == 3:
                board[x][y][1].setFill('blue')                
            elif board[x][y][0] == 4:
                board[x][y][1].setFill('black')

#drawBoard draws the initial board    
def drawBoard(size, board, win):    
    for x in range(size):
        for y in range(size):
            board[x][y][1].draw(win)    
    return

#checks to see if board is white(Winning condition)
def winGame(board, size):
    #steps through all x and y values
    for x in range(size):
        for y in range(size):
            if board[x][y][0] != 0:
                return 0
    #returns true if no black squares are found
    return 1

#valueSwitch() just makes switching values easier by checking values and selecting the appropriate one
def colorSwitch(value):
    if value == 4:
        return 0
    else:
        return value + 1

#bwSwitch only selects from black and white value
def bwSwitch(value):
    if value == 4:
        return 0
    else:
        return 4

#winMessage() displaying a winning message graphic
def winMessage(size, scale, win):
    gameMessage = Text(Point(size*scale/2,size*scale/2),"You have won logic!")
    gameMessage.setSize(int(scale/4))
    gameMessage.setTextColor('red')
    gameMessage.draw(win)      

#gameMenu() is a menu to select game size
def gameMenu():
    win = GraphWin("Logic Menu", 400, 600)
    win.setBackground('light blue')
    board = [[[Text(Point(0,0),'bleh'),Rectangle(Point(0,0),Point(200,200))] for y in range(3)] for x in range(2)]
    #Making and drawing the buttons ;)
    for x in range(2):
        for y in range(3):
            board[x][y][1] = Rectangle(Point(x*200+200*.05,y*200+200*.05),Point(x*200+200*.95,y*200+200*.95))
            board[x][y][1].draw(win)
    board[0][0][0] = Text(board[0][0][1].getCenter(), 'Click for 5x5 puzzle')
    board[1][0][0] = Text(board[1][0][1].getCenter(), 'Click for 7x7 puzzle')
    board[0][1][0] = Text(board[0][1][1].getCenter(), 'Click for 9x9 puzzle')
    board[1][1][0] = Text(board[1][1][1].getCenter(), 'Click for 12x12 puzzle')
    board[0][2][0] = Text(board[0][2][1].getCenter(), 'Click to toggle colors')
    board[1][2][0] = Text(board[1][2][1].getCenter(), 'Highscores!')
    #drawing button options
    for x in range(2):
        for y in range(3):
            board[x][y][0].draw(win) 
    #check to see what button is pressed 
    point = win.getMouse()
    x = int(point.getX()/200)
    y = int(point.getY()/200)
    #colors is either 1 for colors or 0 for no colors
    colors = 0
    #turning colors on and off
    #board[0][2][1] is the rectangle for colors
    while y == 2:
        if x == 0:
            if colors == 0:
                winsound.Beep(400, 200)
                colors = 1
                board[0][2][1].setFill('green')
            else:
                winsound.Beep(363, 200)
                colors = 0
                board[0][2][1].setFill('')
        else:
            winsound.Beep(400, 200)
            board[1][2][1].setFill('red')
            #board is just passed in for a smother button click effect not necessary for functionality
            highscore_board(board)
        point = win.getMouse()
        x = int(point.getX()/200)
        y = int(point.getY()/200)
    board[x][y][1].setFill('red')
    winsound.Beep(400, 200)
    win.close()
    if x == 0 and y == 0:
        return 5 , colors
    if x == 1 and y == 0:
        return 7 , colors
    if x == 0 and y == 1:
        return 9 , colors
    if x == 1 and y == 1:
        return 12 , colors  
    return 5 , colors

#highscore() checks to see if player has highscore and outputs a highscore to a text file
def highscore(count):
    #checks to see if highscore file exists
    try:
        scoreInfo = [line.strip() for line in open('highscore.txt')]
        #remove all spacing
        for i in range(scoreInfo.count('')):
            scoreInfo.remove('')
        scoreInfo[1]
        scores = int(len(scoreInfo)/2)
        newEntry = 0
    #creates new highscore file is none exist
    except:
        win = GraphWin("Highscore!", 400, 200)
        gameMessage = Text(Point(200,100),"Please input name: ")
        gameMessage.setSize(int(scale/4))
        gameMessage.setTextColor('red')
        gameMessage.draw(win)
        name=inputWin()
        f = open('highscore.txt', 'w')
        f.write(name)
        f.write('\n'+str(count))
        f.close()
        gameMessage.setText(name+': '+str(count)+' - saved!')
        time.sleep(1)
        win.close()
        return

    #if there is a new highscore it is added at the beginning of the file
    for i in range(scores):
        if scores < 10 or count < int(scoreInfo[i*2+1]):
            win = GraphWin("Highscore!", 400, 200)
            gameMessage = Text(Point(200,100),"Please input name: ")
            gameMessage.setSize(int(scale/4))
            gameMessage.setTextColor('red')
            gameMessage.draw(win)
            name=inputWin()
            f = open('highscore.txt', 'w')
            #max 10 highscores 9 + new highscore
            if scores >= 10:
                scores = 9
            for i in range(scores):
                try:
                    if count < int(scoreInfo[i*2+1]) and not newEntry:
                        f.write(name)
                        f.write('\n'+str(count))
                        f.write('\n\n\n')
                        newEntry = 1
                    f.write(scoreInfo[i*2])
                    f.write('\n')
                    f.write(scoreInfo[i*2+1])
                    f.write('\n\n\n')
                except:
                    pass
            #if no entries have been added
            #the new value is then added to the end
            if newEntry == 0:
                f.write(name)
                f.write('\n'+str(count))
                f.write('\n\n\n')
            f.close()
            gameMessage.setText(name+': '+str(count)+' - saved!')
            time.sleep(1)
            win.close()
            break
    pass

#board is just passed in for a smother button click effect not necessary for functionality    
def highscore_board(board):
    win = GraphWin("Highscores", 200, 500)
    win.setBackground('light green')
    try:
        scoreInfo = [line.strip() for line in open('highscore.txt')]
        #remove all spacing
        for i in range(scoreInfo.count('')):
            scoreInfo.remove('')
        Text(Point(50,20),"Highscores:").draw(win)
        for i in range(10):
            Text(Point(10,45*i+60),str(i+1)+'. ').draw(win)
            try:
                Text(Point(60,45*i+60),scoreInfo[i*2]).draw(win)
                Text(Point(170,45*i+60),scoreInfo[1+i*2]).draw(win)
            except:
                pass
    except:
        Text(Point(100,250),"no scores yet.").draw(win)
    time.sleep(.05)
    board[1][2][1].setFill('')
    #prevent program crash if scoreboard is exited through os
    try:
        win.getMouse()
        winsound.Beep(363, 200)
        win.close()
    except:
        winsound.Beep(363, 200)

import tkinter as tk

def getString(ment,mGui):
    global hsname
    hsname = ment.get()
    mGui.destroy()
    mGui.quit()

def inputWin():
    mGui = tk.Tk()
    ment = tk.StringVar()

    mGui.title('New Highscore!')
    mEntry = tk.Entry(mGui,textvariable=ment).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    mbutton = tk.Button(mGui,text='OK',command=lambda:getString(ment,mGui),fg='red',bg='blue').pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
    mGui.mainloop()
    return hsname
```

this is the portion that wont work

```
import tkinter as tk

def getString(ment,mGui):
    global hsname
    hsname = ment.get()
    mGui.destroy()
    mGui.quit()

def inputWin():
    mGui = tk.Tk()
    ment = tk.StringVar()

    mGui.title('New Highscore!')
    mEntry = tk.Entry(mGui,textvariable=ment)
    mEntry.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    mbutton = tk.Button(mGui,text='OK',command=lambda:getString(ment,mGui),fg='red',bg='blue')
    mbutton.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
    mGui.mainloop()
    return hsname
```

I'm just screwing around trying to make adding a highscore more visual for a game I made this code it works fine by itself but when I import it or even copy the whole code into a py file with other functions it just stops assigning ment any values I don't understand :/

any help is appreciated

this is the code that runs the game

```
#Josh Harrison
#3008088

from logic_game import *

def playGame():
    option = gameMenu()
    size = option[0]
    color = option[1]

    win = GraphWin("Logic Game", size*scale, size*scale)
    win.setBackground('light pink')
    board = setupBoard(size, color)
    drawBoard(size, board, win)
    countText = Text(Point(scale,scale/2),'moves: 0')
    countText.setTextColor('red')
    countText.draw(win)
    count = 0
    while not winGame(board, size):
        updateBoard(board, size, count)
        selectTile(board, win.getMouse(), size, color)
        count += 1
        countText.setText('moves: ' + str(count))
    updateBoard(board, size, count)
    winMessage(size, scale, win)
    highscore(count)
    #pauses the window and waits for click before continuing
    win.getMouse()
    #closes the window "win"
    win.close()

playGame()
```

link for graphics.py
http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py

Comment: You need to give us an example of a program that doesn't work, instead of giving us an example that works and then trying to describe others that don't.

Comment: sorry im new is there an easier way to upload code then going through every line and spacing 4 times?

Comment: yes, paste your code and then highlight it and hit the curly brace button at the top of the editor, that will format the highlighted text as code.

Comment: OK, better, but it would really help to give a stripped-down example, just enough code to run and demonstrate the problem, rather than everything you've written. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for some tips.

Comment: Also, what exactly does it not do that you expected it to do? Is `inputWin()` returning an empty string no matter what you do? Or raising exceptions? Or what?

Comment: Finally, it looks like you're trying to mix two GUI libraries in the same problem (whatever that `graphics` is, and `Tkinter`). This is almost always a disastrously bad idea. Unless that other library was specifically built to work with Tkinter, they're both going to try to be in charge of the one and only GUI for your program, and one or both are going to fail.

Comment: If you're using a library that doesn't come with Python, like that `graphics` library is, please mention it in the question, tell us what it is, and give us a link.

Comment: As a side note, in your code, you're doing things like `mbutton = tk.Button(…).pack(…)`. That doesn't work. Like most functions in Python that modify a value, `pack` returns `None`, not the modified value. So, if you want to keep `mEntry` and `mButton` around, you have to turn those into two lines of code each—one to create the widget and store it in a variable, and another to `pack` the widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand exactly what your problem is doing wrong, but I'm pretty sure I know what the problem is.

Most of your program is using some library named `graphics` to run a GUI. Then you're trying to use `Tkinter` to run another GUI in the same program.

I don't know what that `graphics` library that is, but unless it's either built on top of Tkinter, or specifically designed to work with Tkinter, this is unlikely to work. Both of them are going to try to be in charge of the one and only GUI for your program, handling all of the events from the user/windowing system, and so forth. One or both are going to fail.

In fact, even if `graphics` *were* built on top of `Tkinter` or designed to work together with it, calling `mainloop` on the `Tkinter` window is at best going to freeze up the rest of your GUI until you exit that `mainloop`, and at worst going to break the outer `mainloop` that the other GUI is relying on.

From what I can see from your other code, that `graphics` library seems to have enough features to do everything you were trying to do with `Tkinter`—create a new window, place some widgets on it, handle a button click. So, why not just use that?

---

Now that you've given us a link to the [`graphics`](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py) library you're using… it looks like a thin wrapper around `Tkinter`. Which means you should be able to integrate them easily. You just have to create a new `Toplevel` instead of a root window (since `graphics` has already created a `Tkinter` root), and not call `mainloop` or `quit` (because you're already in a `Tkinter` main loop created by `graphics`).

Since you haven't given us an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that I can just run and hack on, I've built my own super-simple one around the first example in the `graphics` docs, which does what you were trying to do, and also shows how you can interact with the `graphics` window from the `Tkinter` code.

```
from graphics import *
import Tkinter as tk

def getString(ment,mGui):
    global win
    print(ment.get())
    mGui.destroy()
    win.close()

def inputWin():
    global hsname
    mGui = tk.Toplevel()
    ment = tk.StringVar()

    mGui.title('New Highscore!')
    tk.Entry(mGui,textvariable=ment).pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    tk.Button(mGui,text='OK',command=lambda:getString(ment,mGui),fg='red',bg='blue').pack(side=tk.RIGHT)
    win.getMouse()

def main():
    global win
    win = GraphWin("My Circle", 100, 100)
    c = Circle(Point(50,50), 10)
    c.draw(win)
    win.getMouse() # Pause to view result
    inputWin()

main()
```

It would be better to refactor this to eliminate your global variables, either using an OO design (create a class so you can store things as instance attributes) or a functional design (pass values through closures or bake them in with `lambda`/`partial`, as you're already doing in your `Button` command), but I tried to follow the style you already set in your code rather than rewrite everything.

Comment: I was trying to use tkinter because graphics has no keyboard handling and input using terminal is just kinda lame. 

actually if anyone can help me with some sort of non terminal input that would be awesome aswell this just seemed like the easiest way if it actually worked that is.

Comment: @d4nk1337sauce: Now that you told us what library you're using… it looks like it's built on top of Tkinter, and it's a pretty thin wrapper, too… which means it _should_ be possible to make them work together. Let me take a look and see if I can figure it out.